# How to get integer number with THREE.mapLinear function in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I´m trying to map mouse.x from 0 (a1) to innerWidth (a2), to 0 (b1) to 5 (b2).

so it would be something like:

```
var valueX = THREE.Math.mapLinear(mouse.x, 0, innerWidth, 0, 5);
```

But i need to have integer numbers as result, not float numbers.

in p5.js it would be something like the function "int" before mapLinear.
ex :

```
var valueX = int(THREE.Math.mapLinear(mouse.x, 0, innerWidth, 0, 5));
```

but is not the case in three.js. I already tried "floorPowerOfTwo", but is not it too.

any tips?

thanks!

Comment: Try something like `Math.floor`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Comment: `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()` will do the trick.